# iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available

Tags: pandas

I have an issue, i Want to get those rows which contains missing values. Using iloc and `pd.isnull`, for column 'Mileage' in my table.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('BikeList.csv')
d1=df['Mileage']
print(d1)
print(pd.isnull(df['Mileage']))
d2=df.iloc[pd.isnull(df['Mileage']),['Bike','Mileage']]
```

I am having this error,

```
iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available
```

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('BikeList.csv')
d1=df['Mileage']
print(d1)
print(pd.isnull(df['Mileage']))
d2=df.iloc[pd.isnull(df['Mileage']),['Bike','Mileage']]
```

Answer (score 16):

You need use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), because select by labels `Bike` and `Mileage`:

```
d2 = df.loc[pd.isnull(df['Mileage']),['Bike','Mileage']]
```

Or use [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
d2 = df.loc[df['Mileage'].isna(),['Bike','Mileage']]
```

If need [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is necessary convert boolean mask to numpy array, but also columns to positions of columns by [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
d2 = df.iloc[pd.isnull(df['Mileage']).values, df.columns.get_indexer(['Bike','Mileage'])]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'Mileage':[np.nan,5,4,5,5,np.nan],
         'Bike':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

print (df)
   A  Mileage  Bike  D  E  F
0  a      NaN     7  1  5  a
1  b      5.0     8  3  3  a
2  c      4.0     9  5  6  a
3  d      5.0     4  7  9  b
4  e      5.0     2  1  2  b
5  f      NaN     3  0  4  b

d2 = df.loc[pd.isnull(df['Mileage']),['Bike','Mileage']]
print (d2)
   Bike  Mileage
0     7      NaN
5     3      NaN

d2 = df.iloc[pd.isnull(df['Mileage']).values, df.columns.get_indexer(['Bike','Mileage'])]
print (d2)
   Bike  Mileage
0     7      NaN
5     3      NaN
```

Comment: so for a single label `get_loc()` and for a list `get_indexer()` ?

Comment: I had the same error when using `.iloc` to select rows using a boolean series. This answer pointed me in the right direction: I had to convert to a np mask array using `.to_numpy().astype(bool)`